# break down a long string to integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

thank you for going over my question.

I am green on Python so I would like to ask for your help here. I am using Python 2 on Win7. I would like to break down a string to integers so that I can compare the int values afterwards. I googled some solutions but does not work, please see my code in below.

```
angle = " 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11"
int_lst = [int(x) for x in angle]
print int_lst
```

I got an error that "Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 ***File "C:/Users/Desktop/pythonwifi/LDS Patern - Copy.py", line 2, in <module>
int_lst = [int(x) for x in angle]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"***
```

Any advice please? Thank you very much.

Comment: `map(int, angle.split("  "))`

Answer (score 4):

This line is the issue, because it will iterate the angle string per *character*:

```
int_lst = [int(x) for x in angle]
```

Try this instead, which splits the angle string on whitespace into the relevant pieces:

```
int_lst = [int(x) for x in angle.split()]
```

Comment: Hi @wim, is there a way to remove the '[' and ']' from the result? As in I would like to save the result to a csv file, and the current look in csv file is:   
 | [0 | 1 |  2 | ...| 11] |